# Struct inside subclass, unwrap optional when assigning to self

Tags: ios, swift, struct, option-type

To be honest I couldn't came with better title, so If anyone can suggest something more meaningful it would be great.

Some time ago I saw great talk *Let's Play: Refactor the Mega Controller!* by Andy Matuschak. He showed nice pattern: using struct to inject data to the view, to decouple view's internals from view controller.
It goes like this:

```
class TaskTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    struct ViewData {
        let title: String
        let timingDescription: String
    }

    var viewData: ViewData? {
        didSet {
            textLabel!.text = viewData?.title
            detailTextLabel!.text = viewData?.timingDescription.lowercaseString
        }
    }
}
```

Now as you can see, in `didSet` for `viewData` we update `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` of `TaskTableViewCell`. Well, actually of `UITableViewCell` since both of them are inherited properties.

But this is basic table view cell, I want something customised. I've added `someText` property, and required inits. Now, class looks as follows:

```
class TaskTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    struct ViewData {
        let title: String
        let timingDescription: String
    }

    var viewData: ViewData? {
        didSet {
            textLabel!.text = viewData?.title
            detailTextLabel!.text = viewData?.timingDescription.lowercaseString
        }
    }

    var someText: String

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        someText = ""
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And of course I would like to update `someText`, let's say with `title` property of `ViewData` struct.

```
/// In didSet
someText = viewData?.title
```

which gives me following error:

```
TaskTableViewCell.swift:21:34: Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

Which is weird, because there is no optional String in either `TaskTableViewCell` nor `ViewData`. 
I can fix this with
`someText = (viewData?.title)!`
or
`someText = viewData!.title`
but I would like to avoid force-unwrapping.

Can you explain to me what's happening here?

And why compiler doesn't prints error when assigning to inherited property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
someText = viewData?.title
```

someText is not optional, property title in struct is not optional, but the instance of struct viewData is optional, so viewData's title is optional. So complier will give the error.

UILable's property text is an optional, default value is nil. So
            textLabel!.text = viewData?.title 
is OK.

Comment: Ahhh! Makes sense! If I change `someText` to optional I can, as you said, assign data this way `someText = viewData?.title`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

but there is an optional

`someText` is not optional BUT `viewData` is

`var viewData: ViewData?`, that is why you are forced to unwrap.

you can avoid it like this:

```
someText = viewData?.title ?? "defaultValue"
//equivalent to 
someText = viewData?.title == nil ? "defaultValue" : (viewData?.title)!
```

Comment: It partially makes sense. But I do not have to unwrap `viewData` or it's properties when assigning to `textLabel` or `detailTextLabel`. Why?

Comment: you are doing that in `didSet ` method witch means a value was set, so no need to force one. one more thing AFAIK wen you force unwrap a nil string you get `""` instead of an error